# Incompatible conversion char

Tags: c++, char

I've got tiny problem with my code, from unknown reason compiler pops-up two errors which unables me to compile the following code. The notification I get is:

**multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]**

**incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to char[4];**

Which is weird since I'm assigning char value to char variable. What am I doing wrong ?

```
 #include <iostream> 
 using namespace std; 

 class People 
 { 
    public: 
           int age; 
           char name[4]; 
 }; 

 int main() 
 {
    People arrayP[5] = {{"Paul", 29}, {"Sue", 31}, 
                        {"Jack", 22}, {"Nil", 32}}; 

    arraP[4].name = 'Ope'; 

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) 
    { 
        cout <<"Name: " << arrayP.name[i] << ", " << arrayP.age[i]<<endl
    }
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: That's far from the serious issues here.

Comment: You cannot assign to character arrays (C style strings) that way. You *should* use `std::string` instead (or use C string functions, such as `strcpy`). Also, the `[i]` should be next to `arrayP` and not after the member variable.

Answer (score 3):

You have two errors:

- if you use [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) you must obey the same layout of the class definition. So `{"Paul", 29}` is not correct, while `{29, "Paul"}` is.
- `char name[4]` is too short to contain `"Paul"` since there is no room for the NUL terminator. Since you are working in C++ just use **`std::string`, there are no excuses.**